# When writing out my name in katakana, what should I do with the vowels that don't exist

Tags: katakana, names

I'm learning how to write my name in katakana and I want to learn to do it without using a translator. I tried making my name by looking at katakana charts but my name being Andrew, I don't know what to do with "nd" or making out my name.

Comment: Hint: search for well known people with your name. Here's one that's become controversial in recent times: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC_(%E3%83%A8%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E5%85%AC)

Answer (score 2):

One would place filler vowels where impermissible clusters such as 'dr' form, and substitute for vowels like /æ/ with their closest match, thus making initial /ændru:/ into /andorɯ:/ or even /andorʲɯ:/, those being アンドルー and アンドリュー, respectively. You may also find it useful to check Japanese sources such as wikis for folk with a given name, to see whether there exists a predominant way of transliteration.